# Disable maven settings mirror via local pom

Tags: java, maven

In my maven settings.xml is following snippet:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything to our company mirror -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>[company-mirror]</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

This sends everything to our company mirror and if it can't resolve it, it we will get it from the maven repository.

Now we also receive bug fixes from a vendor from one of our technologies via their maven nexus. Problem is our company mirror doesn't automatically query this nexus, I can easily provide following mirror edit in the settings.xml:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>[vendor-id]</id>
    <mirrorOf>[vendor-mirror]</mirrorOf>
    <url>[vendor-url]</url>
 </mirror>
 <mirror>[company-mirror-settings]</mirror>
</mirrors>
```

And then it will query fine but we can not do this for our company maintained build server which just queries the company mirror.

Is there a way to do it in our local pom.xml/project without touching any external settings?

I have tried following in our pom.xml but it didn't work:

```
<project>
...
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>[vendor-id]</id>
        <name>[vendor-name]</name>
        <url>[vendor-url]</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
</project>
```

running mvn clean install gets following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <project-name>: Could not resolve dependencies for project <project-name>:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Coul
d not find artifact <vendor-dependency> in <company-mirror>
```

Comment: Ask you Nexus admin to add proxy to `vendor-url` in repository group served by `company-mirror`

Comment: As far as I know, the code snippet you've put at the end of your question should have worked. Where did you put it in your POM? (It should be under `<project>`.) What did you observe in the Maven output when it tries to get the artifacts that can only be found on that reporsitory?

Comment: @rkosegi I already did that, but it takes some time before it's implemented and it would be useful if we could edit it in the pom.xml.

Comment: @KevinLH I've put it under the <project> tag I will edit the question to clarify that. I will also put the output of maven in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mirrors definition in `settings.xml` allow for overloading of the default `central` repository as well as any repository defined in the POMs. As a consequence, if your build server uses a settings file with your company-managed repository defined as `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`, it will use it for every single POM-defined repository, and basically ignore these definitions.

So either the `settings.xml` used by the build server should be modified so that not all repository are mirrored, or the company-managed repository should be configured to mirror the repository of the vendor.

[Maven documentation: Using Mirrors for Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)